# NumberFormat.parse is returning unexpected result

Tags: java, parsing, number-formatting

I would expect the following code to throw a ParseException, but it is "2" can anyone explain this or is this a bug in the java implementation? I am running it on the most recent Oracle (1.7.0_05) and osx jvms.

```
    try {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        Number number = format.parse("2 3");
        System.out.println(number);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("2 3 is not a valid number!");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `NumberFormat.parse(String)` may not use the entire text for parsing. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected result.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), NumberFormat.parse does not necessarily use the entire string.

Rule #1 of java programming: always read the documentation!